# Problems with saturation Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: graphics, hp

I have HP laptop with Intel Graphics card. How can I change the saturation? In windows I do it in Intel Graphics Command Center.

Comment: You can use the screen calibration to set up the saturation.
Please read the following article here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-calibrate-screen.html.en